# Angular call controller function from directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I use this fancy select for Ionic http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/CImqy (http://jsfiddle.net/q62jx3s6/ single select!!) and I want when click on item from select to execute a function getCat from MainCtrl

```
 $scope.getCat = function(cat) { ..... }
```

who can help me ?! please )
And i also tried this example, but dosn't work for me ([Angular: calling controller function inside a directive link function using &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using))

Comment: I don't see any code here :  http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/CImqy

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar try to reload page) it's working for me )

Comment: I still don't see any code, have you shared it ?

Comment: or just create a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q62jx3s6/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in MainCtrl's scope and call that function whenever you click any of the options.

```
$scope.getCat = function() { //your code for getCat function }
```

So when you are configuring the options(or countries) you will need to configure it with an onclick attribute or ng-click like this :

```
onclick = "getCat()" or ng-click="getCat()"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know about ng-click, but when i use them on directive this method doesn't work for me!
the getCat is defined in my controller )

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use $scope.$watch and works now for me. but i'll  wait the correct answer

```
    $scope.$watch('val', function() { if($scope.val.single != null)  $scope.getCat($scope.val.single); }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move 'getCat' function from controller to service and then inject service to your directive ?

Calling controller function from directive is not the best solution because then the directive is tight  couple with controller.

**Referring to your comment:**

Maybe you could require controller in your directive, then it is injected to link function in that directive

> When a directive requires a controller, it receives that controller as the fourth argument of its link function.

This topic is described here:
[Angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
in section "Creating Directives that Communicate"

Comment: because 'getCat' works with some scopes and functions from my controller )

Comment: I have modified answer in response to your comment