# AngularJs calling function in link from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a parent  controller and i want to call a function in link from controller but when try to access it gives

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**My Controller:**

```
scope.test = function(m)
{
 linkfunction(m);
}
```

**My Directive:**
     ..........
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

```
 linkfunction = function (n){
  ........somethings........
  }

  ..........
  }
```

How can i call function in link from directive?

Comment: Show proper code not `........somethings........`

Comment: Is that linkfunction in a other controller?

Comment: it is in directive link,not in a other controller,there is only one controller

Comment: If you have to do something like that you are doing something wrong. Expose both methods to the view and when you use ng-click or w/e call both methods there.

Comment: This might be something that you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using

Comment: could you give an example please

Comment: `undefined is not a function`. what is undefined ? Any object?

Answer (score 0):

1) Using Isolated Scope

**HTML**

`<div test-directive callback-fun="testFunction()"></div>`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.testFunction = function(){
  console.log("test")
}
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('testDirective', function() {
     return {
         scope: {
            callbackFun: '&'
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
         {
            scope.callbackFun();
         }
     }
 })
```

2) Without using Isolated Scope

**HTML:**

`<div test-directive></div>`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.testFunction = function(){
  console.log("test")
}
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('testDirective', function() {
     return {
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
         {
            scope.testFunction();
         }
     }
 })
```