# Execute a javascript function within a controller from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to execute a javascript function that resides inside a controller. I need to call the function from within a directive.

The arguments I'm passing are fine. My method name in the controller is "GetAttachments".

When I'm debugging, and using scope, the method name `GetAttachments` doesn't appear.

Can someone please help me to be able to execute the named function?

Here is my directive. I need to know the proper syntax of the line: `scope.GetAttachments(attrs.downloadType, attrs.downloadId)`. Note that my arguments are fine...

```
.directive('download', ['$modal', function ($modal)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        template: '<a style="padding-right: 5px; color:#fff !important;" class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="opendownload()"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>Download</a>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller)
        {
            scope.opendownload = function ()
            {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: root + 'AccountingModule/modal/attachment/download-modal.html',
                    size: 'md',
                    backdrop: true,
                    controller: 'downloadSPDocumentsController as downloadCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        attributes: function () { return attrs; },
                    }
                });
                scope.GetAttachments(attrs.downloadType, attrs.downloadId)
            }

        }
    }
}])
```

Here is my JS function inside the controller:

```
module.controller('downloadSPDocumentsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance', '$location', '$window', 'attributes',
    function ($scope, $http, $modalInstance, $location, $window, attributes)
    {
        var viewModel = this;
        viewModel.attributes = attributes;

        var DocumentDownloadarr;

        viewModel.GetAttachments = function (CheckID, FileID)
        {
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!--<p>For Testing Purpose: Download Type: {{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadType}}</p>
<p>For Testing Purpose: ID: {{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadId}}</p>-->

<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">File Download</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body" cg-busy="{promise:downloadCtrl.promise}">
    <ul ng-init="downloadCtrl.Init()" class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="item in downloadCtrl.DocumentDownloadarr">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="item.FileDescription" ng-readonly="true" />{{item.ExternalDocumentId}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="downloadCtrl.DownLoadAttachment(item.ExternalDocumentId, item.FileDescription)">Download</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class=" btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
        <!--<div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="downloadCtrl.GetAttachments(downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadType, downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadId)">List Attachments</button>
        </div>-->
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose your function *GetAttachments* in the controller via the scope.

Instead of

```
viewModel.GetAttachments = function (CheckID, FileID)
```

try this:

```
$scope.GetAttachments = function (CheckID, FileID)
```

However please note that this will work only if the directive and the controller is sharing the scope (which I think is the case on your code). However if you want to use isolated scope (for better modularity and re-usability) of the directive , then you will have to pass a reference of the method (in your controller) to the directive's scope using '&' binding.

Take a look at this fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/9xktv1hc/) for a demo of isolated scope and calling function in controller from directives

Comment: That did not work.... It did not go inside the method after I changed it to $scope instead of viewModel.....

Comment: Then I think your directive and controller are not sharing the same scope. Can you try using isolated scope? And can you show your HTML?

Comment: I included the HTML. There's no need for me to use isolated scope as the parameters I'm passing to the function are accessible via the attrs property.

Comment: Where have you used your download directive in the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider raising an event in your directive using something like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEventHappened');
```

And then in your controller listen for it with something like:

```
$scope.$on('myEventHappened', function() {});
```

This approach will keep you from tightly coupling your directive to your controller.