# bind controllers $scope in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that use keypup to prevent any null value, the min value must be always 1, it also bound to ng-model and ng-change without rely on the directive.

View

```
<input class="form-control numberOfUsesMustNotNull" type="number" placeholder="Qty" ng-model="qty" ng-change="updatePrice (qty)" />
```

Directive

```
.directive('numberOfUsesMustNotNull', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keyup', function($event) {
                // disallow number of uses to be zero
                if(element.val() === '' || element.val() === 0){
                  element.val(1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem here is when the condition in the directive been triggered, the `updatePrice` function in my controller won't trigger. How do I trigger controller's `$scope.updatePrice` from directive? I think I should not just set the DOM value, but have access to `$scope.qty` in the directive.

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/67s2ktfz/, backspace the number, it will changed back to one but the total isn't updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: calling controller function inside a directive link function using &](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using)

Comment: Hey Jessie, as an aside of what Tah linked - do you know about the min & max attributes you can use a on a number type input? You could put min="1" and if they do lower than that it would mark the input invalid/undefined if you check the ng-model. Doesn't answer your question but prevents the need of a custom directive.

Comment: @IfTrue min='1' doesn't prevent the keypress

Comment: @TahTatsumoto http://jsfiddle.net/67s2ktfz/ try to use a hit backspace, you will know my problem, the link doesn't help, it's a different situation.

Comment: @georgeawg this is too complicated, why not just pass the $scope from directive to controller? or vice versa as there's alrdy 2 way binding.