# How to call a controller function, inside a directive link function using '&' with a parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-directive

I'm trying to pass a parameter into a function, inside of a directive link function, similar to this question: 
[Angular: calling controller function inside a directive link function using &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using)

However, while I've seen a few examples, like this one: [Passing Parameters from a Directive to a function](http://www.whatibroke.com/2013/11/14/passing-parameters-from-a-directive-to-a-function-angularjs/) and I've seen a parameter value get set inside the link inside a directive.  Yet, I've not seen any where you are passing a primitive, like a number in as a parameter to the directive which passes that into the controller function.

I've tried multiple things, but haven't figured out the syntax.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
          <my-directive ctrl-fn="ctrlFn(count)"></my-directive> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.ctrlFn = function() {
      $scope.count = 0;
      console.log('In mainCtrl ctrlFn!');
      $scope.count += count;
     // console.log("count is: " + JSON.stringify($scope.count));
    //Call service here
  };  
})


.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'count' : '&',
      'ctrlFn' : '&'
    },
    template: "<div><button ng-click='ctrlFn({count: 10})'>Click Here</button></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      var count = null;
      scope.ctrlFn = scope.ctrlFn({count: count});
      //scope.text = scope.fn({ count: 0 });
    }
  };
});
```

My plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6uDntNeqe0g343PmeCED?p=preview

Can a primitive get passed in as a parameter in this use case?  If so, what am I missing here?

**Aftermath:**

In case someone is looking for this syntax: `ctrlFn({count: 10})` in the angularjs docs, it's mentioned here under custom directives:

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an
>   expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of
>   local variable names and values into the expression wrapper function.
>   For example, the hideDialog function takes a message to display when
>   the dialog is hidden. This is specified in the directive by calling
>   close({message: 'closing for now'}). Then the local variable message
>   will be available within the on-close expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made two mistakes:

- `scope.ctrlFn = scope.ctrlFn({count: count});` - 
  this line overrides passed reference to a function and sets it to be value returned by this function (`undefined` in this case)
- to pass `count` value to your direcive you should use `=` instead of `&`

Below is code of simplified example.

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.ctrlFn = function(count) {
      console.log(count)
      console.log('In mainCtrl ctrlFn!', count);
      $scope.count += count;
    //Call service here
  };  
})


.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'count' : '=',
      'ctrlFn' : '&'
    },
    template: "<div><button ng-click='ctrlFn({ count: 100 })'>Click Here</button></div>"
  };
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.2" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl"> {{count}}
          <my-directive ctrl-fn="ctrlFn(count)"></my-directive> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well I got one thing right, I asked a question on SO.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: I just went through this, so is there a way to keep the count itself out of the directive code and just pass a value, like 100 from the ng-click to the controller without having to put that into the directives link function?  I'm trying to make this a component and encapsulate the functionality, but I don't want the directive to know anything about the value itself, just pass it along.  I want the value set outside of the directive.

Comment: Sure, answer updated. Actually you do it correctly in you example.

Comment: I was close, but non-working code is worthless.  Thanks for the updated answer!