# Can't call function inside custom directive. Scope is not what I want to use

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I used to have this inside my html 'calculations-td-plan.html'

```
<tr ng-repeat="foodCalculation in selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods">
          <td>{{foodCalculation.food.name}}</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.gram_amount}} g</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.kcal}} kcal</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.proteina}} g</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.cho}} g</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.lipideos}} g</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn--principal btn--xs" ng-click="edtiFoodCalc(selectedmealcalc, foodCalculation, $index)">Editar</button>
            <button class="btn btn--principal btn--xs" ng-click="removeFoodCalc(selectedmealcalc, foodCalculation)">Remover</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Then I create a directive like above.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="( items | filter: { food_option: option } ).length > 0">
    Opção {{ option }}
    <table class="table table-calculo table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Alimento</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="foodCalculation in ( items | filter: { food_option: option } ) track by $index">
          <td>{{foodCalculation.food.name}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn--principal btn--xs" ng-click="edtiFoodCalc(selectedmealcalc, foodCalculation, $index)">Editar</button>
            <button class="btn btn--principal btn--xs" ng-click="removeFoodCalc(selectedmealcalc, foodCalculation)">Remover</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I call this diretive inside 'calculations-td-plan.html' as

```
<div ng-repeat="option in [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <meal-option option="{{option}}"
                 items="selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods"
                 selectedmealcalc="selectedMealCalc"></meal-option>
</div>
```

And this is my directive JS.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nutriApp').directive('mealOption', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  var mealOption = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/checkins/meal-options.html',
    require: 'foodSelector',
    scope: {
      option: "@",
      items: "=",
      selectedmealcalc: "="
    }
  };

  mealOption.controller = ['$scope', 'Food', function($scope, Food) {
    $scope.sumFood = {};
    $scope.summerizeOption = function(foods) {
      if(foods.length > 0){
          $scope.sumFood = Food.summerize(foods);
      }
    };
  }];

  return mealOption;

}]);
```

But now the funcions that I am calling `edtiFoodCalc` and `removeFoodCalc` are not working.

When I put `ng-controller` in my directive it works, (Only call the method) but I can't get the same scope.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="CheckinsPlansCtrl">
```

I am trying to edit with `edtiFoodCalc` and I am not getting the result that I want. I think `ng-controller` creates new scopes when I do `ng-repeat`, and when I did not have a directive the code worked.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in [0,1,2,3,4]">
        <meal-option option="{{option}}"
                     items="selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods"
                     selectedmealcalc="selectedMealCalc"></meal-option>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the `&` binding? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839259/angular-calling-controller-function-inside-a-directive-link-function-using

Comment: Yea @james00794, but I have three *(selectedmealcalc, foodCalculation, $index)* parameters and they are populated inside the directive, one of these is $index.

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are populated inside the directive - you are only passing the **names of the parameters** into the directive. So you would do something like: `<meal-option remove-food-calc="removeFoodCalc(selectedMealCalc, foodCalc, index)"></meal-option>` - now within the directive scope, you would call it like this: `removeFoodCalc({selectedMealCalc: mCalc, foodCalc: fCalc, index: $index})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular's `&` binding, which allows the directive's scope to pass values back to the parent scope. These values don't need to be defined in the controller - they can be defined in the directive and then sent back to the controller.

For example, given a controller and directive:

```
// Controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.funcA = function(value, index) {
    console.log("Called funcA from " + value + " with index " + String(index));
  };

  $scope.funcB = function(value, index) {
    console.log("Called funcB from " + value + " with index " + String(index));
  }
});

// Directive
app.directive('arrayDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "array_directive.html",
    scope: {
      controllerFuncA: "&controllerFuncA",
      controllerFuncB: "&controllerFuncB"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.items = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

      scope.callControllerFuncA = function(i) {
        console.log("Calling controller funcA!");
        scope.controllerFuncA({from: "directive", index: i});
      };

      scope.callControllerFuncB = function(i) {
        console.log("Calling controller funcB!");
        scope.controllerFuncB({from: "directive", index: i});
      };   
    }
  };
});
```

And the following templates:

```
<!-- Controller template -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <array-directive controller-func-a="funcA(from, index)" controller-func-b="funcB(from, index)"></array-directive>
</body>

<!-- Directive template -->
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item}}</div> 
    <div><a href="#" ng-click="callControllerFuncA($index)">Call Controller Func A</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" ng-click="callControllerFuncB($index)">Call Controller Func B</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then use `controllerFuncA` and `controllerFuncB` from within the directive to call the corresponding parent controller functions, `funcA` and `funcB`. Note that these directive functions take an **object** as the parameter, where the keys of the object correspond to the keys that you passed into the directive on the `<array-directive>` tag.

See the attached fiddle and watch the developer console for the complete example: https://plnkr.co/edit/3h8J00ndBk4OQ16C8hf2